# Axis of symmetry of a binary image

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I want to calculate the axis of symmetry of a binary image.

In other words I have an image that has a black irregular shaped object with a white background. I want to find the best approximation of the axis of symmetry that will divide the black part in such a way that if you fold it on that axis that it will have the least non overlap.

I read an article that used moments, but I could not make out how they did this.
I also thought about maybe treating it as a optimization problem, but it also has its drawbacks. (Using a particle swarm for example will require me to test the overlap repeatedly and that would be dead slow)

**Edit:** it does not have to be the fastest option, but I will be running this on 500 or so images.

Comment: I'd say do it as an optimisation. But you could optimise your optimisation proceedure by doing things like taking a initial approximations using a low resolution image, or by sparsely representing the image in terms of edges, or a randomly sampled subset of your image. It'll still be a bit slow. There's loads of algorithms for these things if you look at the machine vision literature, but if you want something quick and dirty that works, a few optimisations on a brute force search would be the way forward IMO

Comment: The problem is that something like a particle swarm literally has thousands of iteration per particle and for each particle iteration we need to test the fitness of that particle. I need to do this on about 500 images and therefore it becomes infeasible.

Comment: OK, I'll outline what I mean in an answer.

Comment: @Murdock: Which algorithm are you referring to when you say thousands of iterations per particle? Is it the standard linear regression (method of least squares) you are referring to?

Comment: @String Linear regression would not work for this(at least I dont think so). I was referring to using a particle swarm where the error function is the amount of non overlapping pixels.

Comment: @Murdock: OK, I do not know enough about algorithms for data analysis so I do not even know how an algorithm based on the non-overlap-error-function would work. Would it converge to a stable axis of symmetry after a finite number of iterations or should it record a sample of errors based on varying axes of symmetry and then choose the optimal from the sample?

Comment: @Murdock: My only thought right now is, that in linear regression the line always passes through the mean of the $x$'s and $y$'s. This point could easily and very fast be determined for a set of black pixels too. But then the slope remains undetermined ...

Comment: @String Correct but the mean could be totally different from the axis of symmetry

Comment: @String a line of symmetry that passes through the centre of mass would probably be a good starting point for an algorithm.

Comment: The symmetry line will pass through the centre of gravity if the object is perfectly symmetric, but it has zero robustness as a single outlying point is enough to arbitrarily change the centre of gravity.

Comment: Thank you all of you! That makes sense. But an axis of symmetry cannot be assumed unique! I mean, a circularly symmetric plot would have any line through the centre of mass as an axis of symmetry.

Comment: @String Yes and any one of them will be fine

Comment: Indeed, but it's a vanishingly unlikely case. (technically you're not going to do any better than $C_4$ symmetry in an image. - assuming > 1 pixel is different)

Comment: @Lucas: Very good point!

Comment: Wouldn't $\infty$ scuttle your noble project or ... are you settling for less?

Answer (score 0):

This would be how I would go about it.

The axis of symmetry in your image would be given by two parameters, an angle $\theta$ and an offset $k$. You need to search this parameter space for a solution that minimises some objective function.

You have some choice about the objective function, should you line up the edges, should you get the largest fraction of matches between the two sides etc.

In any case, you need to specify an objective function, for the absolute difference in values take a function of the form

$$f(\theta, k) = \sum_{X\times Y}|J(x,y) - J(x',y')|$$

Where J is your image, and $(x',y')$ is the reflection of the point $(x,y)$ in the axis of symmetry.

You can speed up your calculation by coarse graining your image (and perhaps using greyscale levels) or by randomly sampling $(x,y)$ coordinates.

Then you use your favorite optimisation method to search, I think a particle swarm method would be overkill. For accuracy, just use a single particle on a lowered resolution image until it converges a bit, increase the resolution, optimise more, and so on. I don't think you need to worry to much about the momentum of the particles either. Pick a point, mutate it, test whether it is better, it wont be super-fast, but it will be acceptable for batch processing 500 images. Better that than spending far longer making a complicated algorithm that might not be any better!

Choose your starting point wisely too. Perhaps using the centre of mass would be a good hint.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that your image isn't just a lot of individual points, otherwise it's hard to efficiently determine where the symmetry line should be even if you know the angle. This will be made precise below where I will state the assumption where I need it.

For any angle $a$:

Require the symmetry line to have angle $a$

Assume that if you sweep the symmetry line across from one side to the other, the amount of overlap as a function of position would be roughly composed of an increasing function followed by a decreasing function

Binary search to find the optimal symmetry line based on this assumption

This should find a reasonably good 'central' symmetry line efficiently

We can make the same kind of assumption about the angle, that the optimal overlap as a function of angle forms a single peak and single trough in each cycle of $180^\circ$, but this is far less likely for typical images, so we can instead assume that adjacent peaks and troughs are separated by at least a certain threshold $d^\circ$, say $d=3$

We then test each slice of $d^\circ$, which has at most one peak, and use a binary search to find the peak within that slice

I think this should do reasonably well, but it would be up to you to fine-tune the parameters for your data set, and you may also want to use the more general assumption of multiple peaks when finding the optimal symmetry line for a particular angle.

Comment: I'm guessing that for everyday objects that do have a line of symmetry this algorithm as is should get within 3% of optimal, but that's just a guess. =)

Comment: Spikeballs with really thin spikes that do not point at the correct angle would of course fail miserably, but I don't think that kind of image is part of your intended data set.

Comment: I am not following exactly. If you only depend on an angle without an offset how will you find the axis

Comment: See the first part under the scope "For any angle $a$", which describes how to find the symmetry line given a fixed angle.

Comment: Clearly at the start of the sweep the object is completely on one side of the line and at the end the object is on the other. Those are the worst with 0 overlap when folded. Somewhere in the middle it will reach the maximum, and usually it won't be too much different from a mountain shape.

Comment: I would expect, even if you didn't use the binary search, and just brute-forced every possibility, it would still be comparable to a particle based search. i.e. (1000 particles)x(1000 iterations) is probably larger than (180deg at 3deg itervals = 60angles)x(image diagonal in pixels).

Comment: @Lucas: I know, but I wanted to use the fact that the overlap varies rather predictably to make it as efficient as possible, which also means that we can handle very large images without down-sampling.

Comment: I understand that. It seems like a sensible optimisation when there is a single convex shape (and some cases which are not). I was more trying say that even if you skipped the efficiencies it would be faster. I just read what I wrote in the message above, I don't know why I said "compatible to", I definitely meant to say "faster than". That said, the down-/sub- sampling method has the advantage of "softening" the optimisation landscape, and will perform better in some cases - but it really depends on the images, and what kind of result is needed.

Comment: @Murdock: Do you understand the idea behind the algorithm or do you need me to give more details?

Comment: @user21820 I understand what you are proposing

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a brute force algorithm for this many years ago. It was slow, so you might not be interested. And full disclosure, I am not a programmer! But FWIW, it worked like this. (Apart from being slow, it did work well.)

Let $S$ be the set of integer $(x, y)$ points belonging to the image.

Because my images had fairly high symmetry about a single axis, with a nearly vertical axis, I parametrized the symmetry axis as $x + by = c$, where $b$ and $c$ are real parameters ($b$ likely small in my application).

Form the set $T$ (which depends on $b$ and $c$) by reflecting each point $(x_0, y_0)$ in $S$ across the line $x + by = c$. The equations for this are
$$x_{\rm new} = (2c-2by_0-(1-b^2)x_0)/(1+b^2)$$
$$y_{\rm new} = (2bc-2bx_0+(1-b^2)y_0/(1+b^2).$$
The reflected coordinates are to be rounded to the nearest integer.

Define the quality function $0 \leq Q \leq 1$ by
$$Q(b,c) = \frac{|S\cap T|}{|S|}.$$
Find the parameter values $\tilde{b}$ and $\tilde{c}$ that maximize $Q$. Then the approximate symmetry axis of the image is $x + \tilde{b}y = \tilde{c}$, and the maximum value of $Q$ is a measure of the symmetry of the image.